# C - Store values of form 0xXX in an array

Tags: c, int, format, hex

I'm trying to create a function that will convert a value into array of the following form:

```
[ [0x03], [0x07], [0xE4] ... ]
```

Why? Because I need to send values to the DDR on an embedded system and the following format is used:

`DDR[0x123] = 0xE4 // Writes E4 to adress 123 starting from sector XXX`

For example, I want to send 500118192 (int) to my memory, it corresponds to the size of my disk in number of sector. In Hexa, it gives 1DCF32B0 and I'd like to write:

```
DDR[0x00] = 0xB0;
DDR[0x01] = 0x32;
DDR[0x02] = 0xCF;
DDR[0x03] = 0x1D;
```

Let's admit that my disk size is stored in a variable called diskSize, is this possible?

Currently, I have the following function but it doesn't work like I'd like to:

```
void intToHex(char * string, unsigned int value, unsigned int size){
    int i = 0;
    for(i = 0 ; i < size ; i++){
        string[i] = 0; // Set every byte to 0
    }
    snprintf(string,size, "%02X", value);
}
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Perhaps `for (i=0; i<4; i++) snprintf(&string[i*2],size, "%02hhX", (value >> (i*8)));`?

Comment: I'm not really good in C, how does `value >> (i*8)` work? Some kind of shift?

Comment: So you want an array of _string literals_? Or what? And what do you mean with "DDR"`? Left apart the former East-German state, it can mean various things, e.g. DRAM or Data Direction Register. Both can apply to embedded systems. Anyway, I suspect there is some very fundamental missunderstanding resulting in an XY-problem. Please state **what** you want to do, not _how_.

Comment: If you work on an embedded project, you should at least know the standard operators.

Comment: `memcpy(DDR, &diskSize, sizeof(diskSize))` ?

Comment: I'm a VHDL-kind of person so C isn't really my field, please excuse my ignorance...
What I want to do is convert an int, let's say 500118192 into the following form: [[0xB0], [0x32], [0xCF], [0x1D]] so that I can send it to the Data Direction Register aka DDR.
I will try the proposed solution tomorrow, thanks for your help.